# FXMLLoader doesn't load from JUnitTest (relative Path Problem)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, javafx

When I call the WindowController Class the loadFXMLItemsAgain() method from my JavaFXAplication Class the absolute path is correct, but the I do the same in the WindowControllerTest (JUnit) it causes that the absolute path wrong the base module .../deliverytool/... is switching to .../deliverytool/deliverytool/... which causes in an error.

I just want that the absolute path to be the same as in JavaFXApplication and I have 100% no Idea where this came from.

I tried to fix it by using getClass.getRessource() which was an even heavier mess: It stoped working in both cases.

Here is a link to the [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1mFS.jpg).

```
//The method in WindowController:
public void loadFXMLItemsAgain() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(new File("deliverytool/Fxml/Window.fxml").toURI().toURL());
        if (loader.getController() == null) {
            loader.setController(this);
        }
        pane = loader.load();
    }
```

```
//The way the method is called in JavaFXApplication
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WindowController controller = new WindowController();
        controller.setVerw(verw);
        controller.setVerwk(verwk);
        controller.loadFXMLItemsAgain();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Deliverytool");
        controller.init(primaryStage);
        controller.show();
        ...
    }
```

```
//The way the method is called in WindowControllerTest JUnit Test Class
public class WindowControllerTest {
    WindowController controller = new WindowController();
@BeforeEach
    public void init() throws IOException {
        controller.loadFXMLItemsAgain();
    }
...
}
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Inteliji IDEA/pizzagesch-ft/deliverytool/deliverytool/Fxml/Window.fxml (No such file or directory)

Should be:

.../Inteliji IDEA/pizzagesch-ft/deliverytool/Fxml/Window.fxml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both 'JavaFXApplication' and 'WindowControllerTest JUnit Test Class' are in te same folder.
It seems like the latter is already in the '/deliverytool' folder.

Comment: Sadly this is not possible because test are in a specified test folder like specified in the maven project structure and many others.

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the project structure.
Try adding "./" before "deliverytool" to ensure it uses to correct relative path to begin with.
`FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(new File("./deliverytool/Fxml/Window.fxml").toURI().toURL());`

Comment: I tried but I get: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Jannik/Documents/Inteliji IDEA/pizzagesch-ft/deliverytool/./deliverytool/Fxml/Window.fxml (No such file or directory)

Comment: I found out it is about Intelijis definition of the Classpath if I change it in the run config it changes, anybody knows how to change a class path via Maven?